# OData provider for DD4T?

Tags: dd4t

Are there any plans to develop an "official" Odata provider for DD4T?  It sounds like that might be ideal for light-weight sites that are not using any of the advanced Tridion features.

I did find a sample OData provider buried in the DD4T forums & tried to get that working.  At the moment it is blowing up in Unity.  For this post I was really just wondering if

1. Is anyone using an OData DD4T provider?
2. What are there thoughts on it if they are?
3. Will there be an "official" one?

Comment: check the dd4t google group. this has been declared done just over this summer.

Comment: Hi Nick - where was this declared "done"? I just finished writing one - did I waste my time?

Comment: I've not seen this either. There is a sample one in the forums somewhere. The repo/contributions are in the process of being sorted out. Chris - you can fork the repository on Github and submit a pull request. https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion

Comment: @ Mr Smith- unless you are using a non compatible programming language, I will prefer broker API over ODATA due to performance reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created an OData Provider. It has not been committed to to the DD4T project yet (I am waiting on access), but I plan to in the near future. But I am happy to share my code base if you drop me an email at stackexchange@urbancherry.net

It is still a bit of a work in progress, but it has page, component, link and binary support. The performance is slower than using the Broker API provider, but it is great for development, as Developers don't need to install any Tridion components on their local machines

Comment: Thanks Chris, have tried the OData provider created by you and it works perfectly but one has to modify the whole solution a lot to remove the dependencies on CD library and building the solution without error :).